# Switching to https (Angular on IIS + Nodejs backend)

Tags: node.js, angular, ssl, iis, https

I have an Angular frontend and a nodejs backend running on the same Windows Server. I serve the Angular app via IIS while letting the backend run on port 3000. When it was set up, it ran with the old http, which is what I want to change now.

For this, I changed the nodejs backend to start up using https and edited the url the frontend tries to reach for backend calls. I used the option in IIS to create a self signed certificate and bound it to the website (as described here: https://support.sophos.com/support/s/article/KB-000038223?language=en_US). Then, I exported the pfx file to use it for the backend aswell.

```js
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https');
// Other stuff
// ...
https.createServer({
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('./backend.pfx'),
    passphrase: '123'
}, app).listen(// Other stuff);
```

This is my first time setting up https, so I don't really know what I'm missing. When I try to use the website, the frontend works, but any backend calls don't get through to it and are instead answered by the browser with ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE.

Is this a problem with the browser and what it allows or is something wrong with the way I tried to make it work?

Comment: How did you create the self signed ssl certificate? Could you please descibe the detailed steps and command you used?

Comment: I edited my question for more information and clarity.

Comment: Are you using the same certificate on IIS and node.js? It seems that you used backend.pfx on node.js, but you did not say what you used on IIS.